# R dplyr using all columns again after select

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking for a way to perform an operation on a selection of columns and then continue to work with all columns again. I would also like to keep the order of the columns. The original selected columns are not needed anymore.

My data has row.names, if that helps

```r
library(dplyr)
data(iris)
iris2 <- cbind(first = iris, second = iris)

iris2 %>%
  select(-contains("Species")) %>%
  scale() #%>%
  #deselect() ??
```

Any ideas on this one? I couldn't find a function like `unselect` or `deselect` but I guess I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: Maybe when previously selected columns aren't needed anymore select just all of them to perform next steps? `select(everything())`

Comment: That is the thing I'm looking for, but in this case it returns `no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double', 'numeric')"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a perfect use-case either for `dplyr::mutate_at` or `dplyr::mutate_if`. In both instances below,

1. the `scale()` function is only applied to the desired columns
2. the column order is retained
3. all column are retained

```
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

data(iris)

# take iris %>% use mutate_at to target all columns that are not the 'Species'
# column and apply the scale function to those columns
a <- iris %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-matches('Species')), scale)

head(a)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1   -0.8976739  1.01560199    -1.335752   -1.311052  setosa
#> 2   -1.1392005 -0.13153881    -1.335752   -1.311052  setosa
#> 3   -1.3807271  0.32731751    -1.392399   -1.311052  setosa
#> 4   -1.5014904  0.09788935    -1.279104   -1.311052  setosa
#> 5   -1.0184372  1.24503015    -1.335752   -1.311052  setosa
#> 6   -0.5353840  1.93331463    -1.165809   -1.048667  setosa


# alternatively, take iris %>% use mutate_if to target all numeric columns  and
# apply the scale function to those columns
b <- iris %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, scale)

identical(a, b)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Well, I knew there had to be a function for this and of course I know mutate()...I was just so focused on select() I did not think about another function in the first place...Thank you!

Comment: The important thing to note is that while the name `select()` might sound like it is "choosing" some columns to operate on, it is actually returning a smaller data frame with only the selected columns. The values in the columns that are not selected are lost.